# Symfony2 Extend Twig Block in Event Listener

Tags: events, symfony, twig, event-listener

I'm trying to find a way to extend a known twig block in an event listener/subscriber.

The code is very basic.

Main twig:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>

{% block body %}{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see it's just a plain html with 2 blocks: body and javascripts.

Now for example I've a event listener onKernelResponse. What I want here is to be able to add new javascript to the "javascripts" block with twig's "extends".

The code could be something like:

```
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
        return;
    }

    $response = $event->getResponse();

    //complete guesswork code to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve

    $content =  $this->twig->extend( //extend() function is imaginary
        $response, //pass in current response
        'AcmeBundle:Javascript:index.html.twig',
    );
    $response->setContent($content);
}
```

The $this->twig->extend should work like $this->twig->render, but instead of render something new, extend() should take the $response and extend it with the 'AcmeBundle:Javascript:index.html.twig' where I can add more content to the "javascripts" block.

Here is the example of the "AcmeBundle:Javascript:index.html.twig":

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <script>
        var something = "new";
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Basically I'm looking for a way to programatically extend twig block in event listeners.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a twig global variable in the event listener to indicate wether to extend the block.

... or you can include the global variable registered in your event listener as template code somewhat similar to `eval` using twig's [template_from_string()](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html) function.

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }} 
    {{ include(template_from_string(global_variable_name|default(''))) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply nifr. What if we have multiple event listeners to append multiple codes into the block?

Comment: register an array variable if it doesn't already exists, add elements to it in each listener  .. then loop over it when including :)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to append elements to the global variable like:
    $twig->addGlobal('js_footer_extra', '<script>var extra = "more"</script>');
But of course this only allows me to override the global variable, not add elements to it. What's the best best way to append to twig global array? Thanks again.